# Excel: How do I find the earliest date and the second earliest date for values that are the same?

Tags: excel

In excel, I have a list of data with over 300 records and I'm looking for a way to find the earliest date for the groups with the same name and the second earliest date from groups with the same list.
for example:

```
     Name    Created 
 1. QWS2000   2/2/22
 2. QWS2000   1/4/22
 3. QWS200    7/6/22
 4. AZ70      1/3/22
 5. ASZ70     4/5/22
```

Based on items with the same name in the "Name" column, find the earliest date and second earliest date.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the approaches you came across in your *looking*, and the problem with those approaches. Also include the version of Excel you are working with.

Answer (score 1):

You may try following formula-

```
=IFERROR(SMALL(FILTER($B$2:$B$6,$A$2:$A$6=$A2,0),COLUMN(A$1)),"")
```

[image]